# Mixing wave files using AudioGraph (UWP)

Tags: c#, audio, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to mix two wave files using AudioGraph api in UWP. I've created the following code which opens two already recorded wave files, creates one AudioGraph, one AudioSubmixNode, two AudioFileInputNode and one AudioFileOutputNode object.

I call graph.Start() to make the graph mix two files and store them into the AudioFileOutputNode. However, what happens is that the AudioGraph never stops and keep expanding the output file. I left it running for a while and the end file became something like 1.1GB until I closed the application!

I tried handling the QuantumProcessed event of the AudioGraph and I noticed that this event gets called endlessly after calling graph.start(). I tried stopping the graph in this event but the event gets called again and again and the end result file gets bigger and bigger.

I was wondering to ask if anybody could help to resolve this problem please.

Many thanks.

```
        AudioGraphSettings setting;
        AudioGraph graph;
        AudioFileInputNode input1;
        AudioFileInputNode input2;
        AudioFileOutputNode output;
        AudioSubmixNode submix;

        IStorageFile musicFile1 = await folder.GetFileAsync("1.wav");
        IStorageFile musicFile2 = await folder.GetFileAsync("2.wav");
        IStorageFile finalFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync("Final.wav", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        setting = new AudioGraphSettings(Windows.Media.Render.AudioRenderCategory.Media);
        CreateAudioGraphResult graphResult = await AudioGraph.CreateAsync(setting);
        graph = graphResult.Graph;

        CreateAudioFileInputNodeResult inputResult1 = await graph.CreateFileInputNodeAsync(musicFile1);
        CreateAudioFileInputNodeResult inputResult2 = await graph.CreateFileInputNodeAsync(musicFile2);
        CreateAudioFileOutputNodeResult outputResult = await graph.CreateFileOutputNodeAsync(finalFile);

        input1 = inputResult1.FileInputNode;
        input2 = inputResult2.FileInputNode;
        output = outputResult.FileOutputNode;

        submix = graph.CreateSubmixNode();
        input1.AddOutgoingConnection(submix);
        input2.AddOutgoingConnection(submix);
        submix.AddOutgoingConnection(output);

        graph.Start();
```

**Edit:** The source wave files are in same length (which shouldn't matter), same bitrate and both have two channels.

Comment: There is a sample [AudioGraph sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/e13cf5dca497ad661706d150a154830666913be4/Samples/AudioCreation), I test it works well.

Comment: @JaydenGu Hi Jayden, thanks for your reply. I've carefully studied this sample but none of the scenarios is about routing AudioFileInputNode to AudioFileOutputNode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mike Taulty, I finally fixed it. Please see below the solution:

```
  this.remainingFiles = 2;
  this.input1.FileCompleted += OnFileCompleted;
  this.input2.FileCompleted += OnFileCompleted;
```

And then we handle the OnFileCompleted as below:

```
async void OnFileCompleted(AudioFileInputNode sender, object args)
{
  if(--this.remainingFiles == 0)
  {
    this.graph.Stop();
    await this.output.FinalizeAsync();
    this.graph.Dispose();
  }
}
```

However, please be aware of the thread safety measures in this event handler.